# Where did Blearnsball come from?

Tags: futurama

In Futurama they no longer play baseball, instead they play a weird, screwed-up version called "Blearnsball." Where did the modifications to the sport of baseball come from?

Comment: Could be derived from Cricket, another weird screwed up game with rules that don't make sense and is also completely imcomprehensible to outsiders.

Comment: @maple_shaft Cricket is what most people believe baseball is derived from but it is still a possibility.

Comment: If you think it has anything to do with baseball just remember this dialog:  Fry: Hey I'm starting to get the hang of this game! The blerns are loaded, the count's three blerns and two anti-blerns and the infield blern rule is in effect, right?

Leela: Except for the word "blern" that was complete gibberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the commentary on season 1 back during the day where the early episodes were coming out, the seven day week did not seem enough to get every day done, so one of the producers (Cohen?) added an eight day to the schedule, Blearnsday. From this day, Blearnsball took its name. As for the actual rules of Blearnsball, I have no idea. But it seems to consist of baseball, pinball, spider-rodeo, and paddleball (the ball is on a rubber string.)

Answer (score 5):

Blernsball comes form the imaginary sport the producers played on [Blernsday](http://tviv.org/Futurama/A_Leela_of_Her_Own#Behind_the_Scenes), the 8th day of the week they invented to fit everything they needed to do in.

Comment: "Technically correct. The best kind of correct."

Answer (score 1):

Blernsball gets its name from Blernsday, which in turn comes from a time when the writers of *Futurama* were working incredibly long, seven-day weeks. David Cohen came up with Blernsday as an extra day on the calendar so the writing staff and producers would have enough time to get all their work done.

Comment: Josh, that's a great bit of information. Do you have a source where we can find the rest of the story?